# Move my custom phtml call after payment information before continue button

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks

How to Move my **custom phtml** call after payment information before continue button in xml
[image]

this is the code

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">   
            <block type="ordercomment/checkout_onepage_review_commentfield" name="cdr_order_comment" template="cdr/ordercomment/onepage/review/commentfield.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this:

   ```
   <checkout_onepage_index>
       <reference name="root">
           <block type="ordercomment/checkout_onepage_review_commentfield" name="cdr_order_comment" template="cdr/ordercomment/onepage/review/commentfield.phtml" />
       </reference>
   </checkout_onepage_index>
   ```
2. Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/onepage/payement.phtml` then add this before your continue button:

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('cdr_order_comment'); ?>
   ```
3. Clear your cache.

Comment: thanks for the reply, please find my latest updated question

Comment: What this code do ?, it is displayed somewhere ?

Comment: actually commentfield.phtml is called before place order but i want to move this to payment information like in the image

Comment: look my edit now

Comment: You're welcome, good luck ;)